# Linux Kernel module build "make modules" get error

Tags: linux

I am using Eclipse Juno, Ubuntu OS 64bit. I try to build Linux modules in Eclipse for ARM platform. Compiler: Sourcery CodeBench for ARM. Eclipse for ARM plug-in installed.

When I run make commands in terminal with root permission, then everything goes on OK.
But when I try build in Eclipse, the make target: "make uImage" is successful but "make modules" and "make modules_install" failed. Below is error i got when I run "make modules". I tried to run Eclipse in root permission (in terminal run: **sudo ./eclipse**) but error still happens. What went wrong here ?. Thanks

```
make -j2 modules
CHK include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
CC scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
CALL scripts/checksyscalls.sh
GEN scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
HOSTCC scripts/mod/file2alias.o
HOSTLD scripts/mod/modpost
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 11 modules
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/acenic/tg1.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/acenic/tg2.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/adaptec/starfire_rx.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/adaptec/starfire_tx.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/dsp56k/bootstrap.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/atmsar11.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2x/bnx2x-e1-6.2.9.0.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2x/bnx2x-e1h-6.2.9.0.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2x/bnx2x-e2-6.2.9.0.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-rv2p-09-6.0.17.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-rv2p-09ax-6.0.17.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-mips-06-6.2.1.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-rv2p-06-6.0.15.fw' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/sun/cassini.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/cxgb3/t3b_psram-1.1.0.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/cxgb3/t3c_psram-1.1.0.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/cxgb3/ael2005_opt_edc.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/cxgb3/ael2005_twx_edc.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
/home/thangle/git/linux-stable/scripts/Makefile.fwinst:45: target `/home/thangle/modules_install/lib/firmware/cxgb3/ael2020_twx_edc.bin' doesn't match the target pattern
```

However, if I build in terminal with command: **make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- modules**

It's OK.

```
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  GEN     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  CC [M]  crypto/rng.o
  CC [M]  crypto/krng.o
  CC [M]  crypto/ansi_cprng.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_loopback.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_sourcesink.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/mass_storage.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/serial.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/zero.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/inode.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/usbstring.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/config.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/epautoconf.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/composite.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/functions.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_acm.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_ss_lb.o
  CC [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/u_serial.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_zero.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/gadgetfs.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_mass_storage.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_serial.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 11 modules
  CC      crypto/ansi_cprng.mod.o
  LD [M]  crypto/ansi_cprng.ko
  CC      crypto/krng.mod.o
  LD [M]  crypto/krng.ko
  CC      crypto/rng.mod.o
  LD [M]  crypto/rng.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/f_acm.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_acm.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/f_ss_lb.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/f_ss_lb.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/g_mass_storage.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_mass_storage.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/g_serial.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_serial.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/g_zero.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/g_zero.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/gadgetfs.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/gadgetfs.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko
  CC      drivers/usb/gadget/u_serial.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/usb/gadget/u_serial.ko
```

regards

Comment: are you not answering your own question?  I -think- you need to make sure you specify in eclipse to cross compile them, else they will probably get compiled for your local machine.

Comment: Hi Chris, I already configured  in Eclipse environtments: ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- modules, INSTALL_MOD_PATH=~/modules_install. Problem is I can build "make uImage" but cannot build "make modules". Thanks